# CSS How to Properly set table elements the same size as the other table elements using css?

Tags: html, css, html-table

First of all, Yes its spaghetti code and I plan on making it more efficient once I can figure out how to make the table elements containing home, basic, show cart and login the same width.

My problem is simple but the problem is this [My Work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3How.png)

But My ideal solution is this [Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1ot2.png)

I tried playing around with the width % and width px but I can't find a solution

Any feedback would be highly appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Basic</title>
  <style>
    .head-box {
      background-color: #808080;
      color: #FFD700;
      font-size: large;
      padding-top: .5em;
      padding-bottom: .5em;
      width: 80%;
      text-align: center;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: black;
      border-radius: 5px;
      text-decoration: underline;
      text-decoration-color: white;
    }
  </style>

  <style>
    /* unvisited link */
    
    a:link {
      color: #808080;
    }
    /* visited link */
    
    a:visited {
      color: green;
    }
    /* mouse over link */
    
    a:hover {
      color: hotpink;
    }
    /* selected link 
                - diplays while the link is being clicked */
    
    a:active {
      color: blue;
    }
  </style>

  <style>
    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      border-style: none;
      width: 200px
    }
    
    .dropbox {
      background-color: #ADD8E6;
      color: #800080;
      font-size: large;
      padding-top: .5em;
      padding-bottom: .5em;
      width: 80%;
      text-align: center;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: black;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
    /* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
    
    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      width: 100%;
    }
    /* Links inside the dropdown */
    
    .dropdown-content a {
      color: black;
      padding: .5em;
      display: block;
      /* <a> is normally inline */
      text-align: center;
    }
    /* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
    
    .dropdown-content a:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
    }
    /* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: gray;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
    /* Change the color of the link
                when hovering */
    
    a:hover {
      color: blue;
    }
  </style>
  <style>
    .body-box {
      background-color: #E6E6FA;
      color: black;
      font-size: large;
      padding-top: .5em;
      padding-bottom: .5em;
      width: 80%;
      text-align: center;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: black;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
  </style>
  <style>
    .foot-box {
      background-color: #B0C4DE;
      color: #FFD700;
      font-size: large;
      padding-top: .5em;
      padding-bottom: .5em;
      width: 80%;
      text-align: center;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: black;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<!--Start of Body Html-->

<body>
  <!--Start of Table

            I set the table as width 80% as required
            Also set the Border to equal 1-->
  <table>

    <!--Start of Table Header-->
    <thead>
      <!--Start of first row in Table--->
      <tr>
        <!--The Name of The Store will
                        Take up 4 columns so I set
                        colspan to 4-->
        <th colspan="4">
          <div class="head-box">
            <h1>Buyers Delight</h1>
          </div>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <!--End of First row Table-->
    </thead>
    <!--End of Table Header-->


    <!--Start of Table Body-->
    <tbody>
      <!--Start of Second row in Table-->
      <tr>
        <!--Used <td> instead of <th> since
                        This is the table body and <td>
                        is often used for Table bodys-->
        <td>
          <div class="dropbox">
            <div class="dropdown"><a href="#">Home</a></div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="dropbox">
            <div class="dropdown"><a href="#">Browse</a></div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <!-- <br> starts a new line-->
        <td>
          <div class="dropdown">
            <div class="dropbox">Show Cart</div>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="#">Clean Cart</a>
              <a href="#">My Orders</a>
            </div>
          </div>

        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="dropdown">
            <div class="dropbox">Login</div>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="#">Logout</a>
              <a href="#">Create Account</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <!--End of Second row in Table-->

      <!--Start of Third row in Table-->
      <tr>
        <!--This will be the description
                        of the Website so It would take
                        4 column spaces so i set
                        colspan to 4-->
        <td colspan="4">
          <!--Used <Strong> to bold font the welcome
                            message-->
          <div class="body-box">
            <h3>Welcome to Buyers Delight</h3>
            This is an Website for an online store that sells rare collectibles that are sold no where else. The site includs a catalog of products and a facility for creating and maintaing customer accounts, complete with a shopping cart for "ordering items".
            <em>Please Note that this is a website for a School Project 
                                and is not a real shopping cart or store website.</em>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <!--End of Third Row in Table-->

    </tbody>
    <!--End of Table Body-->

    <!--Start of Table Footer-->
    <tfoot>
      <th colspan="4">
        <div class="foot-box">We have all Rare Collectibles Here!<br> Contact: <a href="#">My Name</a>
      </th>
      </div>
    </tfoot>
    <!--End of Table Footer-->
  </table>
</body>
<!--End of Body Html-->

</html>
<!--End of Html File-->
```

Comment: well your code is verbose, its unnecessarily complicated, all your css can be between just one set of style tags, but as per your issue, i can see you switched class name probably by mistake. For your "showcart" and "account" boxes, you switched the dropbox class for dropdown class, check your "home" and "browse" to see the differences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't set the table at 80% but the divs. This means that the table is still 100% and that's why the Login box is out. (You can and should check this with

Delete all the width properties and add `table { width: 80%; }` (or create a class for the table tag) in one of your `<style>`; then add a new class just for the 4 boxes with `width: 25%`.

Also you should use a CSS file instead of all those `<style>`

Here is the 'correct' code:

```
 <html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Basic</title>
  <style>
    
    table {
      width: 80%;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    
    .fourbox {
      width: 25%;
    }
    
    .head-box {
      background-color: #808080;
      color: #FFD700;
      font-size: large;
      padding-top: .5em;
      padding-bottom: .5em;
      text-align: center;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: black;
      border-radius: 5px;
      text-decoration: underline;
      text-decoration-color: white;
    }
  </style>

  <style>
    /* unvisited link */
    
    a:link {
      color: #808080;
    }
    /* visited link */
    
    a:visited {
      color: green;
    }
    /* mouse over link */
    
    a:hover {
      color: hotpink;
    }
    /* selected link 
                - diplays while the link is being clicked */
    
    a:active {
      color: blue;
    }
  </style>

  <style>
    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      border-style: none;
    }
    
    .dropbox {
      background-color: #ADD8E6;
      color: #800080;
      font-size: large;
      padding-top: .5em;
      padding-bottom: .5em;
      text-align: center;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: black;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
    /* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
    
    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
    /* Links inside the dropdown */
    
    .dropdown-content a {
      color: black;
      padding: .5em;
      display: block;
      /* <a> is normally inline */
      text-align: center;
    }
    /* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
    
    .dropdown-content a:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
    }
    /* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: gray;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
    /* Change the color of the link
                when hovering */
    
    a:hover {
      color: blue;
    }
  </style>
  <style>
    .body-box {
      background-color: #E6E6FA;
      color: black;
      font-size: large;
      padding-top: .5em;
      padding-bottom: .5em;
      text-align: center;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: black;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
  </style>
  <style>
    .foot-box {
      background-color: #B0C4DE;
      color: #FFD700;
      font-size: large;
      padding-top: .5em;
      padding-bottom: .5em;
      text-align: center;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: black;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<!--Start of Body Html-->

<body>
  <!--Start of Table

            I set the table as width 80% as required
            Also set the Border to equal 1-->
  <table>

    <!--Start of Table Header-->
    <thead>
      <!--Start of first row in Table--->
      <tr>
        <!--The Name of The Store will
                        Take up 4 columns so I set
                        colspan to 4-->
        <th colspan="4">
          <div class="head-box">
            <h1>Buyers Delight</h1>
          </div>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <!--End of First row Table-->
    </thead>
    <!--End of Table Header-->


    <!--Start of Table Body-->
    <tbody>
      <!--Start of Second row in Table-->
      <tr>
        <!--Used <td> instead of <th> since
                        This is the table body and <td>
                        is often used for Table bodys-->
        <td class="fourbox">
          <div class="dropbox">
            <div class="dropdown"><a href="#">Home</a></div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="fourbox">
          <div class="dropbox">
            <div class="dropdown"><a href="#">Browse</a></div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <!-- <br> starts a new line-->
        <td class="fourbox">
          <div class="dropdown">
            <div class="dropbox">Show Cart</div>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="#">Clean Cart</a>
              <a href="#">My Orders</a>
            </div>
          </div>

        </td>
        <td class="fourbox">
          <div class="dropdown">
            <div class="dropbox">Login</div>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="#">Logout</a>
              <a href="#">Create Account</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <!--End of Second row in Table-->

      <!--Start of Third row in Table-->
      <tr>
        <!--This will be the description
                        of the Website so It would take
                        4 column spaces so i set
                        colspan to 4-->
        <td colspan="4">
          <!--Used <Strong> to bold font the welcome
                            message-->
          <div class="body-box">
            <h3>Welcome to Buyers Delight</h3>
            This is an Website for an online store that sells rare collectibles that are sold no where else. The site includs a catalog of products and a facility for creating and maintaing customer accounts, complete with a shopping cart for "ordering items".
            <em>Please Note that this is a website for a School Project 
                                and is not a real shopping cart or store website.</em>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <!--End of Third Row in Table-->

    </tbody>
    <!--End of Table Body-->

    <!--Start of Table Footer-->
    <tfoot>
      <th colspan="4">
        <div class="foot-box">We have all Rare Collectibles Here!<br> Contact: <a href="#">My Name</a>
      </th>
      </div>
    </tfoot>
    <!--End of Table Footer-->
  </table>
</body>
<!--End of Body Html-->

</html>
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I felt like i dug myself a hole by setting width to 200px,Great explanation and Sorry for the spaghetti code. Now i can make it more efficient now that You helped me solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The immediate fix for your problem would be to add this  CSS rule:

```
th > *, td > *, .dropbox {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

(See the snippet below for its effect)

But the real problem is that you defined `width` settings for the *child elements* of your `td` and `th` elements either in fixed pixel values or in percentage values (less than the width of the table cell in many cases).

If at all, you should define those width settings for the `td` elements themselves (using classes or IDs to address them individually), and set their children's width's to 100% (full width of the table cell) - or simply omit using DIVs inside the `td`s, but simply have them containing the actual content, i.e. text

```css
th > *, td > *, .dropbox {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Basic</title>
  <style>
    .head-box {
      background-color: #808080;
      color: #FFD700;
      font-size: large;
      padding-top: .5em;
      padding-bottom: .5em;
      width: 80%;
      text-align: center;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: black;
      border-radius: 5px;
      text-decoration: underline;
      text-decoration-color: white;
    }
  </style>

  <style>
    /* unvisited link */
    
    a:link {
      color: #808080;
    }
    /* visited link */
    
    a:visited {
      color: green;
    }
    /* mouse over link */
    
    a:hover {
      color: hotpink;
    }
    /* selected link 
                - diplays while the link is being clicked */
    
    a:active {
      color: blue;
    }
  </style>

  <style>
    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      border-style: none;
      width: 200px
    }
    
    .dropbox {
      background-color: #ADD8E6;
      color: #800080;
      font-size: large;
      padding-top: .5em;
      padding-bottom: .5em;
      width: 80%;
      text-align: center;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: black;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
    /* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
    
    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      width: 100%;
    }
    /* Links inside the dropdown */
    
    .dropdown-content a {
      color: black;
      padding: .5em;
      display: block;
      /* <a> is normally inline */
      text-align: center;
    }
    /* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
    
    .dropdown-content a:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
    }
    /* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: gray;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
    /* Change the color of the link
                when hovering */
    
    a:hover {
      color: blue;
    }
  </style>
  <style>
    .body-box {
      background-color: #E6E6FA;
      color: black;
      font-size: large;
      padding-top: .5em;
      padding-bottom: .5em;
      width: 80%;
      text-align: center;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: black;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
  </style>
  <style>
    .foot-box {
      background-color: #B0C4DE;
      color: #FFD700;
      font-size: large;
      padding-top: .5em;
      padding-bottom: .5em;
      width: 80%;
      text-align: center;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: black;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<!--Start of Body Html-->

<body>
  <!--Start of Table

            I set the table as width 80% as required
            Also set the Border to equal 1-->
  <table>

    <!--Start of Table Header-->
    <thead>
      <!--Start of first row in Table--->
      <tr>
        <!--The Name of The Store will
                        Take up 4 columns so I set
                        colspan to 4-->
        <th colspan="4">
          <div class="head-box">
            <h1>Buyers Delight</h1>
          </div>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <!--End of First row Table-->
    </thead>
    <!--End of Table Header-->


    <!--Start of Table Body-->
    <tbody>
      <!--Start of Second row in Table-->
      <tr>
        <!--Used <td> instead of <th> since
                        This is the table body and <td>
                        is often used for Table bodys-->
        <td>
          <div class="dropbox">
            <div class="dropdown"><a href="#">Home</a></div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="dropbox">
            <div class="dropdown"><a href="#">Browse</a></div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <!-- <br> starts a new line-->
        <td>
          <div class="dropdown">
            <div class="dropbox">Show Cart</div>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="#">Clean Cart</a>
              <a href="#">My Orders</a>
            </div>
          </div>

        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="dropdown">
            <div class="dropbox">Login</div>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="#">Logout</a>
              <a href="#">Create Account</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <!--End of Second row in Table-->

      <!--Start of Third row in Table-->
      <tr>
        <!--This will be the description
                        of the Website so It would take
                        4 column spaces so i set
                        colspan to 4-->
        <td colspan="4">
          <!--Used <Strong> to bold font the welcome
                            message-->
          <div class="body-box">
            <h3>Welcome to Buyers Delight</h3>
            This is an Website for an online store that sells rare collectibles that are sold no where else. The site includs a catalog of products and a facility for creating and maintaing customer accounts, complete with a shopping cart for "ordering items".
            <em>Please Note that this is a website for a School Project 
                                and is not a real shopping cart or store website.</em>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <!--End of Third Row in Table-->

    </tbody>
    <!--End of Table Body-->

    <!--Start of Table Footer-->
    <tfoot>
      <th colspan="4">
        <div class="foot-box">We have all Rare Collectibles Here!<br> Contact: <a href="#">My Name</a>
      </th>
      </div>
    </tfoot>
    <!--End of Table Footer-->
  </table>
</body>
<!--End of Body Html-->

</html>
<!--End of Html File-->
```